# XSLT rename element with attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new with xslt. and im trying to rename the element name of my *.xml* with the attribute name, and also remove the atttribute.

This is a sample of the XML i want to transform:

```
<configdata>  
 <element xsi:type="AAA">
  <attributes>
     <att1>0</att1>
     <att2>1</att2>
     <att3>25</att3>
  </attributes>
 </element>
 <element xsi:type="BBB">
  <attributes>
     <att4>23</att4>
     <att5>44</att5>
     <att6>12</att6>
  </attributes>
 </element>
</configdata>
```

desired output:

```
<configdata> 
 <AAA>
  <attributes>
     <att1>0</att1>
     <att2>1</att2>
     <att3>25</att3>
  </attributes>
 </AAA>
 <BBB>
  <attributes>
     <att4>23</att4>
     <att5>44</att5>
     <att6>12</att6>
  </attributes>
 </BBB>
</configdata>
```

The xml has hundreds of elements(AAA,BBB,CCC,DDD...) so, any general solution would be great.

I've tried with the following xslt code but in the output i keep the input xml with no change at all.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
version="1.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="element">
 <xsl:element name="{@xsi:type}">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I would appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="element">
 <xsl:element name="{@xsi:type}">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
 </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

You want to process all children of `<element>`. However, `<xsl:value-of select="."/>` does not do that. All it does is outputting the text content of an element.

Comment: Hi, Tomalak,thanks for your answer. I've tried with:                             <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="element">
    <xsl:element name="{@xsi:type}">
      <xsl:value-of select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>                                                                              But in the output i only get de value of the atributes..                      0125  234412

Comment: I did not say you should drop the identity template. ;)